# Count and group by in a referenced table, selecting other attributes

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count, reference

I have two tables: account_table and branch_table.

```
create table branch_table(
    id int,
    address varchar
);

create table account_table(
    accid int,
    balance int,
    type varchar,
    branch_ref ref branch_type
branch_ref SCOPE IS branch_table
);
```

How do I list the number of accounts of type 'saving' per branch, and select the address of this branch as well?

Comment: you can do it by using a Join and an Aggregate function.

Comment: Trying grouping by both `id` and `address`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote an answer and only then noticed that you are using Oracle's object orientated features. I have no idea how to select from such tables and found almost nothing on the Internet. If you are just starting, you might want to use classic relations instead, i.e. a branch_table_id in account_table. Then it's just simple standard SQL join and aggregation. And it would be much easier to find help on the Internet with a classic model I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.address,COUNT(*) AS no_of_accts
  FROM account_table a
INNER JOIN 
       branch_table b
    ON a.branch_ref = b.id 
 WHERE a.type = 'saving'
GROUP BY b.address;
```

Comment: It tells me: SQL Error: ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method
22950. 00000 -  "cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method"
*Cause:    an object type must have a MAP or ORDER method defined for
           all comparisons other than equality and inequality comparisons.
*Action:   Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type

Answer (score 0):

For each branch there will be unique address and we can do group by operation on both of those columns or we can do group by on branchid and then take max of address this doesnt change anything. And also need to do group by on account type to get type wise details.

```
SELECT b.id, b.address,COUNT(accid) no_of_accts
  FROM account_table a
INNER JOIN 
       branch_table b
    ON a.branch_ref = b.id 
 WHERE a.type = 'saving'
GROUP BY b.id,b.address,a.type;
```

Comment: Why selecting max(b.address) ? Makes no sense as an address is a varchar

Comment: it doesn't matter where it is number or varchar for using max of function but here I have used it because there is for each branch id you will get unique branch address so instead of putting it in group by I have taken that one as max of address. there is no difference if we keep it group by also... Now I have changed it you can try now.

Comment: Thank you. However in both case I get this mapping error : SQL Error: ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method
22950. 00000 -  "cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method"
*Cause:    an object type must have a MAP or ORDER method defined for
           all comparisons other than equality and inequality comparisons.
*Action:   Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type